# Load webpage in div on mouse-over effect of link

Tags: javascript, html, mouseout, mousehover

I am developing a website (using php, html and css). I have a page for "news and events" which contains list of urls. What I want to do is on mouse-over over a link, a small miniature of the corresponding website should be loaded in a div, so that the user knows what type of news the link contains.

I have tried code on mouse-over for images and videos, but unable to do the same for webpage.

For image :

```
<a href="Happy-Birthday-1.gif" rel="enlargeimage" rev="targetdiv:loadarea,link:dynamicdrive.com">Happy Birthday</a><br /> <div id="loadarea" style="width: 600px"></div>
```

For Video :

```
 <a onClick="document.getElementById('dynloadarea').innerHTML='<iframe src=\'osmosis.mpg\' width=\'300\' height=\'300\' scrolling=\'auto\' frameborder=\'0\'></iframe>'"> Osmosis</a> <div id="dynloadarea"></div>
```

-Thanks in advance !

Comment: For image : <a href="Happy-Birthday-1.gif" rel="enlargeimage" rev="targetdiv:loadarea,link:http://dynamicdrive.com">Happy Birthday</a><br />
<div id="loadarea" style="width: 600px"></div>

For Video : <a onClick="document.getElementById('dynloadarea').innerHTML='<iframe src=\'osmosis.mpg\' width=\'300\' height=\'300\' scrolling=\'auto\' frameborder=\'0\'></iframe>'">
Osmosis</a>

<div id="dynloadarea"></div>

Answer (score 0):

use blockUI 
examples are here :
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
   var imgpath = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#loadarea').load(imgpath)
}, function(){
   $('#loadarea').empty()
})
```

Comment: I think this will only work if the pages you are trying to load are on the same server.

Comment: @soupy1976 yes, the images are on the same server.

Comment: @undefined : I can load images/videos. I want to load webpage in div on hover-effect!

Answer (score 0):

You will need jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$('a').hover(function(){
   var path = $(this).attr('href');//Get the path
   $('#result').load(path);//Load contents into a div#result
   , function() {
     $('#result').show();
   }
});

$('a').mouseout(function(){
 $('#result').hide();
});
```

You will only be able to load pages on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#a').mouseover(function(){
$('#page').css('visibility','visible');
       $('#ss').attr('src',"http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp");
});

$('#a').mouseout(function(){
$('#page').css('visibility','hidden');
});
});​


<a href="Happy-Birthday-1.gif" rel="enlargeimage" r id="a">Happy Birthday</a><br />
<div id="page">
<iframe width="300" height="300" scrolling="auto" id="ss">
</iframe>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I tried your code but the link doesn't display anything on div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<p id="p3"><a href="http://apple.com">Apple</a></p>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://codegena.com/assets/css/image-preview-for-link.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://codegena.com/assets/js/image-preview-for-link.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#p3 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'parenthover' });
        $('#p3 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'pageload' });
    });
</script>
```